# do you think fixie can beat gear/non-fixie bikes?should i buy new bike?

Tags: mountain-bike, road-bike, fixed-gear

i have hero hawk(road bike) which is 10 years old do you think i can beat non fixie bike with this or should i buy new bike?

do you recommend fixie or non-fixie bikes?

Comment: Based on pictures on the web, the Hero Hawk appears to be a reasonably well-outfitted standard road bike, with caliper brakes and derailleur gearing.  If it fits you and the quality is reasonably decent it should give you reasonable service.  Whether you can beat another bike depends more on you than on the bike.  Only buy a fixie if you live on flat ground or you're a bit of a nut.

Comment: It's mostly about the engine (you) more so than the bike. I ride a single speed (as well as my road bike) regularly and easily past 80-90% of people on my commute but that's down to my fitness/strength levels.

Comment: On your second question, a single speed bike might be appropriate where you don't have many changes in gradient. Beyond that, whether you ride it fixed or non-fixed is down to personal preference (well, and likely the limitations of the bike). I don't think your first question is on-topic for this site.

Comment: One question per question.  Why would be buy a bike just because another bike might be faster?   Why did you tag the mountain-bike?

Comment: @DanielRHicks  means if the same person will ride the bike than he/she will give better timing on fixie compare to non/geared bike.

Comment: @ynnekkram if you ride the fixie and than geared that means your timing is better on fixie compare to non...

Comment: @SSangeet - Your time's only going to be better (or as good) on a fixie if it happens to have the ideal gear ratio for the course, given your level of fitness.

Comment: BY THE WAY ANSWER OF THIS QUESTION IS NOT ENTIRELY BASED ON OPINION,I NEED SOMEONE WHO ACTUALLY RIDE THE SAME BIKE WITH GEAR & NON GEAR MODE SO I CAN GET BEST ANSWER...

Answer (score 1):

To help you answer your first question,

> do you think i can beat non fixie bike with this or should i buy new bike?

Leave your current geared bike in one gear combination for the day and see if you like it.  Ride a route you're familiar with and know your average time.  Ride your bike in this one gear combination, did you beat your time or was it slower?  And most importantly was it a fun ride.

Regarding your second question,

> do you recommend fixie or non-fixie bikes?

It really comes down to personal preference.  Riding fixed is not something you just do one day.  It takes commitment to learn to ride smart.  You really have to pay attention to your surroundings, your body, and your bike because you can seriously injure yourself if you just forget you can't coast.

Comment: here with fixie means with breaks also...

Comment: Some people believe that not being able to coast is dangerous and requires expertise.

Comment: A fixie cannot coast and brake not break.

Comment: using clipless pedals mitigates the "forget you can't coast"